# rails-money gem: Money formatting with 2 cent digits, but storing 4 cent digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I am using the RubyMoney / money-rails gem and I am very happy with it.

Now I need to add more precision to the money column, so I defined a new currency with

```
:subunit             => "Subcent",
:subunit_to_unit     => 10000,
```

Is there a way to use the format helper humanized_money_with_symbol but showing only 2 digits after the comma?

Example:
10,0044 € (Money fractional:100044 currency:EUR )
should be displayed as
10,00 €

Answer (score 5):

E little dirty trick is unregistering all the currencies and re-registering them with the new `subunit_to_unit` like so

```
currencies = Money::Currency.table.dup

currencies.each do |code, currency|
  Money::Currency.unregister(currency)
end

currencies.each do |code, currency|
  Money::Currency.register(currency.merge({subunit_to_unit: 1000}))
end
```

If you are using Rails try declaring the above code in a initializer.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for storing without adding new duplicate currencies, a precision of more than 2 digits in the database. Life saver!

Comment: If we are reregistering the currencies on an existing app would we need to run a manual update to all existing records to multiply the existing values by 10?